# How to detect sentence stress by python NLP packages (spaCy or NLTK)?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

Can we detect the [sentence stress](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/sentence-stress.htm) (the stress on some words or pauses between words in a sentence) using common NLP packages such as spaCy or NLTK?

[image]

How can we tell content words from structure words using spaCy or NLTK?

Since all NLP programs detect the dependencies, there should be a possibility to identify which words are stressed in natural speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that NLTK or spacy support this directly. You can find content words with either tool, sure, but that's only part of the picture. You want to look for software related to prosody or intonation, which you might find as a component of a text-to-speech system.

Here's a very recently published research paper with code that might be a good place to start: https://github.com/Helsinki-NLP/prosody/ . The annotated data and the references could be useful even if the code might not be exactly the kind of approach you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not have a special training data set with labeled data in what words to stress. So I guess the simplest way would be to assume, that stressed words are all of the same Part-of-speech. I guess nouns and verbs would be a good start, excluding modal verbs for example. 
NLTK comes with [PoS-Taggers](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html).

But as natural speech depends  lot on context, it's probaly difficult for humans as well to identify a single solution for what to stress in a sentence.